# How to disable https redirect in one directory with htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I use this code to redirect every directory and www to https:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=301]
```

And this rewrite:

```
RewriteRule ^download/([0-9]+)?$ index.php?page=Download&fileID=$1 [L,QSA]
```

How to accept both http and https request in the "download" directory?
For example: **http**://localhost/download/123 and **https**://localhost/download/123 should both work without redirect.

Comment: You place the download rule as an exception _before_ the more general rules for the redirection. Keep in mind that rulies are processed one after another - from top to bottom.

Comment: Can you provide example how to do the exception?

Comment: I don't think just changing the order is enough. Yes, the `L` flag will prevent processing of further rules - but only for the current "round". Since this is configured in .htaccess, the whole process loops until there are no more matches. But going into the second round with `http://localhost/index.php?...`, that download rule won't apply any more, so it is then free to proceed to the following rules, and apply those.

Comment: _"How to accept both http and https request in the "download" directory?"_ - why, what is the point of that?

Comment: Before what? Can you please provide code example? If i place "RewriteRule ^download/..." at the second line (after RewriteEngine On), it does not work, it stil redirects, but it redirects to https://...index.php?page=Download&fileID=X

Comment: The point is that the content is dynamic and refreshes via javascript. The content occasionally needs to be accessed by old devices which do not support self signed certificates and then the auto-refresh does not work because of certificate warning..

Comment: So no one on stack overflow knows this? :D